# Call CreateProcess() and get return value of a string

Tags: c#, c++, return-value, createprocess

I have a C++ application that calls an EXE written in C# which grabs some information, and I want to pass it back as a string to the calling C++ application.

So my question is, "is it possible to get a return value of string data from an EXE called with CreateProcess()?

I hope I didn't violate any "question" etiquette here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the C# app outputs its data to STDOUT or STDERR, the C++ app can capture it by redirecting STDOUT/STDERR when it calls `CreateProcess()`.  See [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) on MSDN for details and examples.

Answer (score 1):

No worries Jeff yes there is a way to get the data from one to the other though the EXE.

What you will want to do is write your output in the C# application to standard output.

```
Console.WriteLine("Your message here.");
```

Basically if you run the C# console application and it prints data to the screen all that data can be read in your C++ application.

In your C++ program you will want to read from standard input.

It may look something similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Your code to run the application in a background process

    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The only rule you broke was not providing enough detail or code to get more specific about the solution. But if you need more help just provide more details. Happy coding!

Here is a link to more information about the c# code if you need it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how another process can return a string. Processes don't return anything, they just run.

You can reference (or link) some DLL or EXE and then call a method returning a string. But this will run within your own process and not start another one.

See: [Calling C# .NET methods from unmanaged C/C++ code](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/695387/Calling-Csharp-NET-methods-from-unmanaged-C-Cplusp) (CodeProject).

Comment: "Processes don't return anything, they just run" - No. Processes return a status code to the OS when they exit. There's a reason `main` returns `int`.

Comment: The OS expects an `int` return code. If you are in control of the .NET part, then you would create a DLL (i.e., a Class Libraray), not an EXE. If you are not in control, then you cannot change the return code and the return code is just a side-effect for you, and not what you expect as result. But we really should know in detail what this other application does.

Comment: @Oliver Jacot-Descombes The C# program does WebResquests and captures the Response, in this case it checks to see if a license is active on my Website.


If it is active, it then sends the license information to my C++ application, which processes it, and determines if it is valid and should startup.